# Books with more problems on card/urn and ball problems

Tags: reference-request, book-recommendation

I am struggling with combinations and permutations. One particular concept that is bugging me is selecting outcomes.

I posed a few questions in a forum.

\What is the probability that you are dealt a "full house"? (Three cards of one rank and two cards of another rank.)\

I received following answer

""When counting the number of full house hands you have to choose from which of your two selected ranks the 3 suits will come and from which the 2 suits will come. Two ways to calculate this
${13 \choose 2} {2 \choose 1} {4 \choose 2} {1 \choose 1} {4 \choose 3}$
or
${13 \choose 1} {4 \choose 2} {12 \choose 1} {4 \choose 3}$""

but again when I tried to solve another problem using the same method,

Another Question: What is the probability that you are dealt a "two pair"? (Two pairs of cards where each pair contains two cards of the same denomination, with the fifth card of a different denomination. Note that we exclude four of a kind from this definition.)

My approach is as follows

$\large{\frac{{13 \choose 2} {2 \choose 1}{4 \choose 2}{1 \choose 1}{4 \choose 2}{52-4-4 \choose 1}}{{52 \choose 5}}}$

but it wasn't quiet right,

and when I asked why this does not work, I was told

"In the full house case it was necessary to distinguish which rank had 3 cards and which rank 2 cards. In this case there is no way to distinguish because both ranks have the same number of cards.
${13 \choose 2}{4 \choose 2}{4 \choose 2}{11 \choose 1}{4 \choose 1}$""

This concept is quiet new to me.

Apparently I am missing something basic about combinations. What would be a good book or webpage or any kind of educational material, where I can practice these type of combination and permutation problems? I would also value comment from educators who have seen students struggling to solve these type of counting problems.

Comment: Permutations and combinations is some kind o elementary combinatorics. So, famous books like Brualdi, Daniel A. Marcus(MAA) won't help you much. You try to follow any standard high school level book with exercises on Permutations and combinations try to think more deeply into problems. I think then you can study higher standard books on Combinatorics.

Comment: Thanks __________    ____